# Append XLSM files in folder using Python with filename in the first column

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I am a Python beginner. I have successfully appended `.xlsm` files with a particular sheet name from a folder using a Python script. However I need the filenames of each file that is appended in column A too.

Here's the script:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

data_file_folder = r"C:\..."

df = []
for file in os.listdir(data_file_folder):
    if file.endswith('.xlsm'):
        print('Loading file {0}...'.format(file))
        df.append(pd.read_excel(os.path.join(data_file_folder, file), sheet_name = 'B...'))

df_master = pd.concat(df, axis=0)
df_master.to_excel('A... .xlsx', index=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) each *filename* into the first column `0/"A"` like this :

```
list_df = []
for file in os.listdir(data_file_folder):
    if file.endswith('.xlsm'):
        print('Loading file {0}...'.format(file))

        tmp = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(data_file_folder, file), sheet_name = 'B...')
        tmp.insert(0, 'filename', file.split(".")[0]) # <- here we insert the filename

        list_df.append(tmp)

df_master = pd.concat(list_df, axis=0)
df_master.to_excel('A... .xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy help. One more thing, my files have ' . ' within their names. If I wanted to keep everything, would I just remove the ' file.split(".") ' bit and keep the [0]?

Comment: You're welcome. In this case, use `file.rsplit(".", maxsplit=1)[-2]`.

Comment: Hi, I would like to take this a step further with specific columns containing specific column headers. Would that be possible?